# QGIS does not polygonize

Tags: qgis, raster, geotiff-tiff, polygonize, vectorization

I have a .tif which I want to have polygonized. I take the Raster/Conversion/Raster to Polygon. QGIS 3.12 starts the process but never ends (once I waited half an hour). I maybe don't see a mistake. [image: white has the value 1 and black the value 0]

White has the value 1 and black the value 0. I also tried with ArcMap where it is the same: The process starts but it never ends.

Comment: Can you share the tif?

Comment: Polygonizing rasters are slow. Half an hour is not a long time, let it execute over night

Comment: If you want to speed this up and have the technical skills to do so, save the raster to postgis and do it there https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_DumpAsPolygons.html

Comment: 1. steps: There is not much I can do. I choose the tool Raster/Conversion/Raster To Polygon. There I just choose the proper layer, choose the output filename and say 'start'

Comment: 2. How do I share the tif? It has a size of 49MB
3. I dont think it is the time. I did polygonization of much bigger files and it worked within a few minutes.
4. i will try ti do it in PostGIS

Comment: It is possible that the polygons from that binary raster will be extremely complex multipolygons. GDAL used to be rather slow with building such complex geometries. There has been some optimization on this area lately. It may be worth having a try with gdal_polygonize from GDAL 3.2.

Comment: ok now after 4 hours it finished. Didnt know that it would take so long